# How dangerous is it to output certain content without escaping it first

Tags: php, html, content-management-system, xss

Following on from a question I asked about escaping content when building a custom cms I wanted to find out how dangerous not escaping content from the db can be - assume the data ha been filtered/validated prior to insertion in the db.

I know it's a best practice to escape output but I'm just not sure how easy or even possible it is for someone to 'inject' a value into page content that is to be displayed.

For example let's assume this content with HTML markup is displayed using a simple echo statement:

```
<p>hello</p>
```

Admittedly it won't win any awards as far as content writing goes ;)

My question is can someone alter that for evil purposes assuming filtered/validated prior to db insertion?

Comment: It depends on how you filter/validate. But just to be sure, I would *always* escape. Maybe google for "Cross Site Scripting" / "XSS".

Comment: Where does the displayed data come from?

Comment: How did you filter that HTML? How did you ensure that no scripts can be inserted? There are thousands of tricks to do that, so cutting out `<script>` and inline event handlers is not enough.

Comment: Thanks guys, let's assume content is added to the db using a form and pulled back from the db for output. The main form fields are filtered and validated to make sure just text values however the content field itself (which contains various markup HTML and JavaScript) has been left pretty open maybe using only a simple strip tag function.  I'm wondering if someone can override the values of your variables with their value. My understanding isn't great so I'm wondering if someone can change something like echo $page->content so it will output phpinfo()? Do you know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not escape your HTML output, one could simply insert scripts into the HTML code of your page - running in the browser of every client that visits your page. It is called [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

For example:

```
<p>hello</p><script>alert('I could run any other Javascript code here!');</script>
```

In the place of the `alert()`, you can use basically anything: access cookies, manipulate the DOM, communicate with other servers, et cetera.

Well, this is a very easy way of inserting scripts, and `strip_tags` can protect against this one. But there are hundreds of more sophisticated tricks, that `strip_tags` simply won't protect against.

If you really want to store and output HTML, [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) could be your solution:

> Hackers have a huge arsenal of XSS vectors hidden within the depths of
>   the HTML specification. HTML Purifier is effective because it
>   decomposes the whole document into tokens and removing non-whitelisted
>   elements, checking the well-formedness and nesting of tags, and
>   validating all attributes according to their RFCs. HTML Purifier's
>   comprehensive algorithms are complemented by a breadth of knowledge,
>   ensuring that richly formatted documents pass through unstripped.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to help, I'm assuming this would only work if an attacker can access the form and add the content to the database?  Does a CSRF token added to the form coupled with a solid ACL arrangement make this a much smaller risk in your opinion? I'm thinking of site admins adding new content.

Comment: @notQuiteAnExpert It's more about the scripts that handle the form than the form itself - those should double check for the rights. If there is only a few people that have access (and it is not easy to break into the admin system of course), there is CSRF protection, it is not a huge risk, but still a risk.

Comment: Thanks again, so do you think a reasonably sensible approach would be display the form only if the user is authenticated and the user is authorized to access it then check when the form is posted if the user is authorized to add/update/delete relevant field then handle the outcome? I'd like to mitigate as much risk as possible while allowing flexibility for admins regarding script tags and custom attributes in the content field?

Comment: @notQuiteAnExpert If the admins can add script tags and custom attributes through a web interface, you will never be REALLY safe. But if this is a requirement (and you cannot say you will not implement it), I'd say the described way (with the added CSRF, session fixation, etc. protection) will be "good enough".

Answer (score 2):

*Always escape for the appropriate context;* it doesn't matter if it's JSON or XML/HTML or CSV or SQL (although you should be using placeholders for SQL and a library for JSON), etc.

Why? *Because it's consistent.* And being consistent is also a form of being lazy: you don't need to ponder if the data is "safe for HTML" because *it shouldn't matter*. And being lazy (in a good way) is a valuable programming trait. (In this case it's also being lazy about avoiding having to fix "bugs" due to changes in the future.)

Don't omit escaping "because it will never contain data that needs to be escaped" .. because, one day, over a course of a number of situations, *that assumption **will** be wrong*.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to help, I like the idea of getting it so right I can be lazy ;) appreciate the advice I'm thinking mainly of site admins adding content and giving as much flexibility as possible for adding custom attributes. Once I can up vote I'll be sure to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It could be, for example, also problem linked with some other vulnerabilities like e.g. sql injection. Then someone would b e able to ommit filtering/validation prior adding to db and display whatever he can.

Comment: Thanks for that I'm thinking utilizing prepared statements in all db updates is the way to go, thin intending the forms will only be used by admins adding new content. Any thoughts?  Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pulling the word hello from the database and displaying it nothing will happen. If the content contains the `<script>` tags though then it is dangerous because a users cookies can be stolen then and used to hijack their session.

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate you taking time to reply ;)